# Compare all elements of a std::vector with every other element in the same vector efficiently

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdvector

I'm new to C++.

I'm trying to find how to iterate through a vector to compare every element with every other element, where the comparison order is irrelevant where;

> (a 'compared to' b) = (b 'compared to' a)

So checking one means you don't need to compare every value to EVERY other value, just the remaining ones.

I have something that's like this TOY algorithm;

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> vector_t;

int countTheFoo(const vector_t &v)
{
  int fooFound {0};
  for (auto it1 = v.begin(); (it1 != v.end()); it1++)
  {
    for (auto it2 = it1.next(); (it2 != v.end()); it2++)
    {
      if testForFoo(*it1, *it2)
      {
        // Woot! Found some...
        fooFound++;
      }
    }
  }
  return fooFound;
}

vector_t foo { 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 };

int numFoo {countTheFoo(foo)};
```

I'm actually comparing lines to find ones which intersect not simple doubles but the technique would be the same.

It's the;

```
for (auto it2 = it1.next(); (it2 != v.end()); it2++)
```

part that I think could be done more efficiently using lambdas.

This approach works, but;

- Is it the most efficient way of doing this sort of iteration?
- Can it be done as a *lambda* using *std::for_all()*?

Thank you.

Comment: Is a greater than/ less than relationship defined? If so, you can sort the lists and it will be possible to avoid comparing everything

Comment: Don't know if that would work... I'm ACTUALLY comparing lines which INTERSECT not simple numbers so I was looking for a generalized form for the solution NOT simple doubles.

Comment: You will get a wrong cont if the vector contains three (or more) equal elements

Comment: If most efficient means performance:  Yes (the code is efficient, besides you should get used to pre-increment ++it) If most efficient means maintainability: Maybe (however, the code is still easy to grasp)

Comment: @Dieter Yes. I have used lambdas and find them easier to understand and quite neat. BTW is there some big difference using pre-increment instead of post-increment?

Comment: @DavidHParry Not here, but you might use a more complex iterator sometime (eg.: by making the code a template/general algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't need to test `(it1 != it2)` because by the definition of your loop on `it2`, `it2` will always be greater than `it1`. Efficiency will be increased if you delete that phrase from your code.

You *probably* could use `std::for_all` but it's not clear that that would increase the efficiency of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::set`, and a single loop to check if the value in the vector already exists in the set; and if not insert it.

This is really what `std::set` is for. It'll be hard to come up with a lookup implementation that will outperform `std::set`.

Comment: `std::sort` can easily outperform `std::set`

Comment: std::lower_bound and std::binary_search on sorted vector are both binary searches with logarithmic compexity. Drawback is that you either have to sort vector or insert elements in sorted manner (again, with e.g. lower_bound) which *can* trigger reallocations and copies. For relatively small collections of data even linear search (find_if) will be faster than searching the set because of processor caching.

Comment: This does not make any sense. If the predicate were an equivalence relation and the OP had access to a compatible weak order, he would do much better by simply sorting the data and comparing adjacent elements (no binary search either).